# Installing a package inside RStudio fails on macOS Catalina

Tags: r, rstudio, macos-catalina

While trying to install a package inside `RStudio` on `macOS Catalatina,` it fails with a `Permission Denied` error:

```
> install.packages("mlbench")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mlbench_2.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 920768 bytes (899 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 899 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mlbench’ ...
** package ‘mlbench’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
mv: rename /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/library/mlbench to /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/library/00LOCK-mlbench/mlbench: Permission denied
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/library/mlbench’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mlbench’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/bc/wsz930gj3gn5zgq4hbm6jkfr0000gn/T/RtmpdvQLox/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot create file '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/doc/html/packages.html', reason 'Permission denied'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot update HTML package index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554786-Problem-Installing-Packages) by RStudio Support:

> **Are you able to install packages in R?**
>
> If you're having issues, we recommend trying to install packages in R
> (outside of RStudio) and see if you're able to do that. If not, please
> check the possible solutions below.

Therefore, one needs to:

- switch to `Terminal.app`,
- while inside your Terminal, your R console **must** be started with the `sudo` privileges. Otherwise, it will yet again fail with a permission denied error. Hence, inside your Terminal, type `sudo R`,
- and then install whatever package is necessary: e.g. `install.packages("mlbench")`.